# Win32 API waveInGetErrorText declaration into C#

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

Need to call

```
MMRESULT waveInGetErrorText(
   MMRESULT mmrError,
   LPTSTR   pszText,
   UINT     cchText
);
```

From C# code. Didn't find the declaration at PINVOKE.net.
The description of the func is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd743842(v=vs.85))

MMRESULT is just an uint value. 0 - no error.. any other value up to 20 - are errors.

Tried lot of patterns. Always get back an empty string.

```
[DllImport("Winmm", EntryPoint = "waveInGetErrorText")]
public static extern uint waveInGetErrorText(uint mmrError, IntPtr pszText, uint cchText);
```

When call.

```
uint r = 12 // for example return value is 12
uint szErrorMessage = 128;
string errorMessage = new string(' ', (int) szErrorMessage);
IntPtr strPtr = Marshal.StringToBSTR(errorMessage);

r = waveInGetErrorText(r, strPtr, szErrorMessage);
```

The return string is always empty reserved 128 bytes of spaces.
Tried `ref` and `out` without success..

Pls, any idea why?

Comment: can you try `public static extern uint waveInGetErrorText(uint mmrError, string pszText, uint cchText);` and `public static extern uint waveInGetErrorText(uint mmrError, StringBuilder pszText, uint cchText);` ?

Comment: was it `string` or `StringBuilder`? :)

Comment: StringBuilder..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your definiton of:

```
public static extern uint waveInGetErrorText(uint mmrError, 
                                             IntPtr pszText, 
                                             uint cchText);
```

...isn't enough to tell .NET that `IntPtr pszText` is outputting anything.  By default all paramaters are decorated with `[in]` marshal attributes by the compiler.  So your above definiton is equivalent to:

```
public static extern uint waveInGetErrorText([in] uint mmrError, 
                                             [in] IntPtr pszText, 
                                             [in] uint cchText);
```

Now if you had a definition like:

`int CountRecords (out int numErrors)`

...the compiler turns that into:

`int CountRecords ([out] out int numErrors)`

...I believe. Regardless, the `out` (either form) tells the compiler to expect something from the p-invoke.  Because you did not specify `out` or `[out]`, nothing is passed back into the parameter after completion of the call.

Now you could use `out string` but `StringBuilder` is easer.  Some types like `StringBuilder` are recogised by .NET as *"hey, for this parameter I expect something in return"*.  The `out` is optional.

Change your definition to:

```
[DllImport("Winmm", EntryPoint = "waveInGetErrorText")]
public static extern uint waveInGetErrorText(uint mmrError, StringBuilder text, uint cchText);
```

I believe you should be calling it like so:

```
uint r = 12 // for example return value is 12
StringBuilder data = new StringBuilder(255);
r = waveInGetErrorText(r, data, data.Capacity);
```

### Tell me more

- *[When is it necessary/appropriate to use InAttribute and OutAttribute for COM Interop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593345/when-is-it-necessary-appropriate-to-use-inattribute-and-outattribute-for-com-int/8593413#8593413)*