# Using Win32 API to get desktop work area rectangle

Tags: c#, winapi

I Want SystemParametersInfoA to return a System.Drawing.Rectangle but i have no idea how to proceed.

Here is my code so far:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, out IntPtr pvParam, uint fWinIni);
const uint SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030;

void GetRect()
{
    IntPtr WorkAreaRect;
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, out WorkAreaRect, 0);
}
```

Comment: When doing P/Invoke, the pinvoke.net site is your friend. Start here: https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.SystemParametersInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to pass a buffer variable in.

But you don't need to manually allocate it. You can just use an `out` variable.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, out RECT pvParam, uint fWinIni);
const uint SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}

Rectangle GetRect()
{
    if(!SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, out var r, 0))
        throw new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
    return new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Does it really work? `SPI_GETWORKAREA` does not allocate a `RECT` and return it. Did you mean to use `ref` instead of `out`?

Comment: No I did mean `out`, which also implies `[Out]`. The difference between `out` and `ref` for structs is purely in compile-time semantics of initialization. Specifying `[Out]` or implying it also changes the copy semantics if there is any marshalling done. The memory is allocated either way and passed in as a pointer. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8593413/14868997 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/26653492/14868997

Comment: i forgot to come here to give feedback but thank u guys it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Per the `SPI_GETWORKAREA` documentation:

> The `pvParam` parameter must **point to a [`RECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/windef/ns-windef-rect) structure** that receives the coordinates of the work area, expressed in physical pixel size.

The pointer in question is not an `out` value. It is an `in` value. You are supposed to pass in your own pointer to an existing `RECT` instance, which `SPI_GETWORKAREA` will then simply fill in.

You can use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal()` to allocate memory for a `RECT`, and then use `Marshal.PtrToStructure()` to extract the populated `RECT` from the memory.

Try this:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(uint uiAction, uint uiParam, IntPtr pvParam, uint fWinIni);
const uint SPI_GETWORKAREA = 0x0030;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}

void GetRect()
{
    IntPtr mem = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(RECT)));
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, mem, 0);
    RECT r = new RECT;
    Marshal.PtrToStructure(mem, r);
    Rectangle WorkAreaRect = new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width, r.Height);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(mem);
}
```